# How to set Video Stabilisation parameter in CameraX?

Tags: android, android-camerax

I am using `CameraX` in my application & want to use in build video stabilization feature but I don't know how to do that?

As it is documented in [Camera.Parameters](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html?authuser=1#setVideoStabilization(boolean)), There are 3 methods which we can use `public void setVideoStabilization (boolean toggle)`, `public boolean isVideoStabilizationSupported ()` and `public boolean getVideoStabilization ()`  for real time video stabilization but I didn't find any reference to use these functions in CameraX. If it is not possible with `CameraX` then should I use `Camera2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think with cameraX you can not set these parameters, You need to use either `camera-api` or `camera2-api`

Following is the way to use `STABILIZATION` mode in Camera2

```java
...
captureRequestBuilder = cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
//Either of these two mode you can use one. 
captureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_VIDEO_STABILIZATION_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_VIDEO_STABILIZATION_MODE_ON);

captureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.LENS_OPTICAL_STABILIZATION_MODE,CaptureRequest.LENS_OPTICAL_STABILIZATION_MODE_ON);
```

You can find explanation of these mode [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureRequest.html#CONTROL_VIDEO_STABILIZATION_MODE)

Comment: You used the template "TEMPLATE_PREVIEW"!!!
It should use with "TEMPLATE_RECORD" template.

Comment: One should remember: it should use in both places: TEMPLATE_PREVIEW and TEMPLATE_RECORD.
As video stability needed to be in the recorded video too.

Answer (score 1):

Actually and technically you can do it with the latest CameraX. But you have to use the non-public (yet?) API for LIBRARY_GROUP only.
Here is how I can disable stabilization in my app:

```
val configBuilder = Camera2ImplConfig.Builder()
configBuilder.setCaptureRequestOption(
                CaptureRequest.CONTROL_VIDEO_STABILIZATION_MODE,
                CaptureRequest.CONTROL_VIDEO_STABILIZATION_MODE_OFF
)
    
configBuilder.setCaptureRequestOption(
                CaptureRequest.LENS_OPTICAL_STABILIZATION_MODE,
                CaptureRequest.LENS_OPTICAL_STABILIZATION_MODE_OFF
)
...
...
//After you bound your use cases
(camera.cameraControl as Camera2CameraControlImpl).addInteropConfig(configBuilder.build())
```